# Высокая нагрузка на ЦП при выполнении программы

Tags: c++, winapi, циклы

При вводе количества секунд начинает грузить процессор.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int time,x,y;
    bool state = false;
    cout << "Time between clicks(in ms): ";
    cin >> time;
    cout << "Press F12 to activate / deactivate the script.";
    POINT mouse;
    while(true)
    {       
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F12))
        {
            if (state == false) 
            {
                state = true;
                Sleep(250);
            } else
            {
                state = false;
                Sleep(250); 
            }
        }
        if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000 && (state == true))
        {
            GetCursorPos(&mouse); 
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,mouse.x,mouse.y ,0,0); 
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,mouse.x,mouse.y ,0,0); 
            Sleep(time);
        }
        if (GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x8000 && (state == true))
        {
            GetCursorPos(&mouse); 
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP,mouse.x,mouse.y ,0,0); 
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN,mouse.x,mouse.y ,0,0); 
            Sleep(time); 
        }
    }
}
```

Что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Comment: Разгрузить программу используя Sleep внутри цикла на пару милисекунд. У вас кстати, Sleep присутствует, но не вызывается постоянно, а нужно вызывать или каждый цикл (само проще), или хотя бы раз в 100 циклов. Допишите  `Sleep(1)` после while - сразу увидите результат.

Comment: когда использую sleep то появляется задержка клика

Comment: и sleep вызывается для очерёдности между кликами

Comment: У вас два варианта решения проблемы 1)Вызывайте  Sleep раз в 10 циклов, или раз в 100 циклов, иначе ваша программа будет забирать 100%. 2) вызывайте синхронные функции работы с клавой. (думаю вам не подходит, вы же чего-то взяли асинхронные)

Comment: А нельзя сделать ожидания действия без цикла?

Comment: Попробуйте ещё WaitForInputIdle (ожидание событий ввода, если возник ввод мышкой или клавой - ожидание прерывается).

Comment: `nanosleep` и установить 1/3 секунды, тормоза пропадут и кликать будет нормально. Ещё можно asm вставку сделать с дериктивой `nop` и подобрать оптимальное количество

Comment: @NewView `Sleep` позволяет задать интервал 1/3 секунды, и автор с `Sleep` уже знаком. К чему тот nop.  `Sleep` - дает команду процессору отдохнуть, и переключится на другой процесс.

Comment: Тогда через Sleep и делать, юниксовый sleep в секундах вроде..

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно вызывать GetAsyncKeyState в цикле только с целью глобального отлова нажатий клавиатуры или мыши. При таком способе у вас всегда программа либо слишком сильно нагружает процессор, либо недостаточно быстро реагирует на события. Вместо этого, используйте специально для этого предназначенный механизм, Low-level keyboard (mouse) hook:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

bool state = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{    

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
            if(p->vkCode == VK_F12) {               
                state = !state;             
            }           
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc( int    nCode, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:            
            if(state != false) {
                //выполнить необходимые действия при нажатии кнопки мыши...             
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    printf("Press F12 to activate / deactivate the script.");

    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);
    if(hook == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to install keyboard hook!\n");
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, 0, 0);
    if(hook == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to install mouse hook!\n");
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {    
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }       

    return 0;
}
```