# Как остановить поток?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

Как сделать чтоб поток переставал выполняться когда ЛКМ перестает быть зажата?
Есть такой код:

```
void spray()
{
mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
Sleep(100);
mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
Sleep(100);
mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
Sleep(100);
mouse_event((0x0001), 0, 3, 0, 0);
Sleep(100);
mouse_event((0x0001), 0, 3, 0, 0);
Sleep(100);
}
```

Он должен выполняться когда зажата лкм,и что самое важное,если мы отпустили ЛКМ он должен перестать выполняться,т е прерваться на одной из mouse_move.
Если это можно как то реализовать без потоков,то тоже вариант неплох.
Я пишу так:

```
byte n=1;
while (true)
{
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) & 0x8000)
    {
        if (n == 1)
        {
            n = 0;
            thread thr(ak47);
            thr.detach();

        }
    }
    else 
    {
 //Было бы круто тут остановить поток thr
        n = 1;
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том ,что код выполняется полностью,даже когда кнопка не нажата.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 4):

> Я пишу так:

Не надо. Пишите так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/963930/240512

Что касается остановки потока, проще всего это сделать какой-нибудь атомарной переменной-флагом:

```cpp
std::atomic<bool> should_stop=false;

void spray()
{
    mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
    Sleep(100);    
    if(should_stop) return;
    mouse_event((0x0001), 1, 4, 0, 0);
    Sleep(100);
    if(should_stop) return;
    //...    
}

//...

should_stop = true; //остановить поток
```

Comment: condition лучше в таком кейсе)