# Мышь отправляет сообщения, но куда? Откуда их доставать для использования?

Tags: c++, winapi, мышь

У меня обычный "пустой проект" в VS2019(С++), я нашёл как найти координаты окна и курсора,

```
POINT mouse;//точка с координатами мыши
while (1)
{//тут я просто определяю координаты куда нажал мышкой относительно окна и пишу это
    GetWindowRect(hwndConsole, &rc);
    GetCursorPos(&mouse);//записываем в точку координаты курсора
    std::cout <<"Position WINDOW   "<< rc.left << "\t" << rc.top << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Position MOUSE   " << mouse.x << "\t" << mouse.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Position MOUSE by WINDOW   " << mouse.x - rc.left << "\t" << mouse.y - rc.top << std::endl;
    _getch();
}
```

но совершенно не понимаю как начать принимать MESSAGE от мыши о её нажатиях и движении. И если я таки начну получать сообщения от неё, то как их лучше обрабатывать, в бесконечном цикле или есть какая-то специальная функция "ждать сообщение от мышки" ? И как я понимаю в отдельном процессе это делать, чтобы в основном делать то, что нужно при нажатиях на кнопки или это происходит как-то автоматически? 
И ещё, есть ли какие нибудь особенности при работе с консолью?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages

Comment: странно, я весь сайт макрософт перерыл и вот конкретно на эту страницу не натыкался, хотя она самая важная. Я конечно попытаюсь сейчас разобраться но хорошо бы увидеть реальный пример кода

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работать из консоли с мышью - необычно. Внезапно консоль - это элемент **текстового** интерфейса, который заточен на работу с символьными данными... Консольные приложения обычно не получают как таковых "MESSAGE", но они могут использовать функцию [ReadConsoleInput](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) для получения событий мыши, если включить режим `SetConsoleMode(hStdin,ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT)`. Фактически да, по принципу "ждать сообщение от мышки". [Пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events).

Также консольные приложения могут установить глобальный хук на мышь, и тогда они будут получать сообщения о событиях мыши во всех приложениях. Их в этом случае можно обработать с помощью обычного цикла GetMessage/DispatchMessage. [Пример работы с хуками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/927170/240512)

GUI-приложения обычно могут проще взаимодействовать с мышью, обрабатывая [сообщения мыши](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/inputdev/mouse-input-notifications) типа `WM_MOUSEMOVE` в своих окнах.